# Remove question title length limitation

Tags: feature-request, titles

### The reason title length exist

Because it's useful to prevent spam on most of the other site, you would not like to see bunch of 1 character question flooding.

### But...

I already meet the situation a few time before, that I named the question properly, but it's still under 15 character, for example: `Repeat average` have only 14 char, inconveniently just below 15 character limit although it being the best title I can use to explain the problem.

### What I actually want to say

I know it's difficult to change title length specifically just for one site, and it's not a huge inconvenience to a point where it should be change immediately, but there aren't any meta question that talked about this question, so I am putting it up here to gather your thoughts about this feature that may can be improved.

### my advice

If we can, I am thinking of removing the title length limitation and only limit to *at least have title*(or title length > 0), or we can lower the limit to 10/5 bytes, allowing some short terms that perfectly describe the problem to be used in title, let anyone scrolling through the question list have a better understanding of what you question might be about in the first place.

Comment: Given the looser nature of titles here, this would be a nice thing to have. However, if this were to happen, it would almost certainly be a CGCC-specific change (the title limit was raised from 10 to 15 on SO in 2009 and hasn't changed since), and the reasons for this change aren't really significant enough to motivate it